# Why am i getting this error message am getting: (property of null)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I tried practising Dom in js with a video I watched.

**Html**

*input id="hi" type="submit"*

**Javascript**

var hi = document.getElementById('hi');

hi.text content ='hello';

But the text content didn't change. It instead gave an error: property of null. What is my mistake and what does that mean

Comment: Did you key it in exactly as `hi.text content ='hello';`?

Comment: content in hi.text  is surplus

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a space in any variable/method names. JavaScript will think you're defining two separate things.

Instead of: `hi.text content = 'hello';`

Try: `hi.textContent = 'hello';`